# Why would Joshi rather die than reveal K's whereabouts?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

It seems unwise for Joshi to give up her life so easily. She died for nothing. Luv still used her devices to locate K.

Joshi believed K had finished his job. All the key evidences except the bones stolen by Luv were thought to be eliminated. **Why did Joshi still think K's whereabouts were more important than her own life?**

Comment: It's a matter if principle, yes Luv got the information, **but not through Joshi**.

Comment: I was just thinking the same question, but you beat me to it. +1 anyway. I am curious to see what the answer is.

Comment: **Officer K was just as much the property of LAPD as a smart-car or a laptop computer.** Joshi telling K to go hide and keeping Luv from finding him makes as much sense as Joshi telling a smart-car to drive away all by itself and hide itself so it can't be reclaimed by its manufacturer. She has no reason to do that.

Comment: @LincolnMan except people not always act purely on reason. Have you never been emotionally attached to an object? Favorite pen, toy or tool? How about to an animal -pet dog or cat? For Joshi K might be just a tool (a smart car as you named it), but it is HER tool, her pet,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Joshi wants to protect the 'wall'

Joshi believes that the world needs to remain the way that it is, and for people to realise that Replicants can now become pregnant would destroy the world as they know it. She's willing to die to protect that truth from getting out.

### The world is built on a wall

You'll recall, that Joshi explained the way the world works to K:

> **INT. JOSHI’S OFFICE. MOMENTS LATER.**
> Evercalm Joshi pours herself a drink. A safeguard on that
> calm. She picks up her drink with a shaking hand. Finally --

> JOSHI
> *That’s not possible. She was -- a
>
> Replicant. Pregnant. It was pregnant.
>
> She quiets with the alcohol burn.
>
> Stares out. Seeing too many steps ahead. Into darkness*.
> [She sets her glass down with finality. Finally looks to K,
> firm, declaring:]
> JOSHI (cont’d)
> (firm)
> *The world’s built on a wall that
>
> separates kind. Tell either side there’s
>
> no wall -- you bought a war -- or a
>
> slaughter.*
> (and then)
> *So what you saw. Didn’t. Happen.*

> K
> *Yes Madam.*

> JOSHI
> *What isn’t possible can’t be.*

> K
> *Yes Madam.*

> JOSHI
> ***There’s an order to things. This turns
>
> it. That’s what we do here, we keep
>
> order.***

> [K catches on. What Joshi is asking.]
> K
> *You want it gone?*

> JOSHI
> *Everything.*

> K
> *Even the child.*

> JOSHI
> *We have to break the mold. All trace.
>
> Numbers, incepts. Erase. Everything.*
>
> <sup>*-Blade Runner 2049, Final Shooting Script, Fancher, H. and Green, M. 2017.*</sup>

And how if it were to 'break', this wall would cause the whole world to collapse, so it would have to remain intact.

### Defiant to the end

Joshi is *so* sure of the need for this wall to remain intact, that **she's willing to die to protect it**:

> **INT. JOSHI’S OFFICE. POLICE STATION. NIGHT.**
> [Joshi at her desk, the lights dim giving visual precedence to
> THE CITY MAP she has UPSCREEN: Real time feed of current
> police activity. The lights go abruptly BRIGHT.
> An unfamiliar woman has just stepped into Joshi’s office with
> presumed intimacy, turned the lights on. LUV.]

> LUV
> *Too dark in here.*
> [Joshi sits back in her chair. Her silence a challenge to
> this stranger.]
> LUV (cont’d)
> *Your pet. I liked him. He’s a good boy.
>
> Where is he?*
> [Luv steps closer. Joshi nods knowingly. Saw this coming.
> She shuts her SCREEN down.]

> JOSHI
> *So you’re who’s looking.*
> [Luv gives a polite bow. And just like that, all cards are on
> the table.]
> JOSHI (cont’d)
> *No idea. He’s off duty, reward for a job
>
> well done. Check around.*

> LUV
> *I checked. Anywhere a good boy might go.*
> [Joshi pours a short one and takes it ahead of what’s coming.
> **As usual she sees too many steps ahead and knows her mind
>
> about where it goes.** And then --]

> JOSHI
> *You’re too late. It’s gone. He
>
> destroyed it. Everything about it.
>
> Except a box of bones you already took.
>
> Which I’ll wager wasn’t enough. Here you
>
> are.*

> [Luv’s perfect face twists. Lightning quick, Luv snatches
> Joshi at the hand holding the glass. Crushes it.]
> LUV
> *You tiny thing. **In the face of the
>
> fabulous new your only thought is to kill
>
> it. For fear of great change. You
>
> can’t hold the tide with a broom.***

> JOSHI
> [(defiant, ready)]
> *Except that I did.*

> [Luv squeezes her dead hand even tighter. Cruelly.  ]
> LUV
> *Where is he?*
> [Joshi is in blinding pain. Channels it into silence.  ]
> LUV (cont’d)
> *You’re so sure. Because he told you.
>
> Because we never lie? I’m going to tell
>
> Mister Wallace you tried to shoot me
>
> first. That’s why I had to kill you.*

> JOSHI
> *You do what you got.*
>
> <sup>*-Blade Runner 2049, Final Shooting Script, Fancher, H. and Green, M. 2017.*</sup>

In the 1st emphasised part, the writers tell us that Joshi has realised that Luv doesn't believe the piece of the puzzle is removed. She's "thinking too many steps ahead" at all times, so she understands that Luv isn't going to give up.

You'll notice too that in the 2nd emphasised part, even Luv has realised that Joshi's intention is to keep the truth from getting out.

Whether she was right or wrong, it doesn't matter, it's what Joshi believed. She died protecting what she believed.

Comment: [Well, I'm not wrong](https://twitter.com/andmichaelgreen/status/1273076281165230080)